# Is there a easy way to pass variables from PHP (Laravel) to my CSS pre processor (LESS)?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, less

I need to pass different values from my database to my LESS variables but i could not found an easy, simple, or a "feel right" way to do it

The only way I was able to accomplish this was with JavaScript doing the below code, but it feel too much like a work around. Any suggestions?

```
<script>
    const r = document.querySelector(':root');
    r.style.setProperty('--blue', {{$color}});
</script>
```

Comment: That is exactly the way to do it.  Otherwise your javascript has to make an ajax call back to the server which is an unnecessary round trip.

Comment: I've personally never had any success passing PHP variables to CSS (or Sass/Less, etc.). You can use a `<style>` tag in a `.blade.php` file, like `<style> h1 { color: {{ $color }}; } </style>` would work (assuming `$color` contains valid CSS, like `#FFF`, etc.), or you can define classes and do `<span class="{{ $example }}">` or similar.

Comment: as saying Toby Allen, it's exactly the way to do. It's not a work around a css var is at root level, you add or change a css var this way. You will see it in console as property of your document

Comment: To be clear, there's no reason to get JavaScript involved unless you have a specific need for it, it really adds more complexity than necessary. The CSS function `var()` accepts a variable name as the first parameter, and an optional fallback value as the second. If the variable doesn't exist, the fallback is just used. The fallback variable is also scoped so it can be safely set in a bunch of ways: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/wvYXmvR. For fully customizable things, we'll just kick out either an inline style attribute or tag with the specifics, or for "themes" we'll just have variant files